# "[" in custom cite-command made with \DeclareCiteCommand

Tags: citing, footnotes, footcite

For my work i need a custom cite command, which creates a footnote with a custom style.
For that i use the `\DeclareCiteCommand` command:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\xfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote][\unspace]
 {\usebibmacro{citeindex}
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}
\printtext{Vgl}
\printnames{author}
\printfield{prenote}
\printfield{year}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
}
```

The footnote itself works, however there is a `[` at the beginning of the footnote, which looks like this:

[image]

The `[` appears when i use `[\unspace]`, however if i remove it, there is an empty row with only a dot in it between the footnotes:

[image]

Is there a way to have the footnote without the `[` and no empty rows?
I'm not working with LaTeX for a long time, so i could not figure it out myself and didn't find any questions like that

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: Try wrapping the `\unspace` within `{}` instead of `[]` (cf. page 176 of the BibLaTeX manual for version 3.14). Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography), so that suggestions like this can be easily tested.

Comment: using {} instead of [] result in the empty rows with dots like in the Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like the following

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\xfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]{%
\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\iffieldundef{prenote}{\printtext{Vgl}\adddot\addspace}%
{\printfield{prenote}\setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
{\printnames{author}\addspace
\printfield{year}}%
{\multicitedelim}%
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\xfootcite{westfahl:space}

\xfootcite{angenendt,westfahl:space}

\xfootcite[See][]{westfahl:space}

\end{document}
```

`\DeclareCiteCommand` takes five mandatory arguments and only one optional one.  Your syntax with `[\unspace]` looks like a second optional argument, but was being read as the first three mandatory arguments `[`, `\unspace` and `]`.  The spaces in your output were being added by end of line characters, which you need to comment out with `%` at appropriate places.

I have tried to guess how you might want to use the prenote.

Comment: It works thank you so much :) i was really frustrated because it didn't work for me. but your solution works exactly how i wanted it to be.

Comment: I can vote you :-)..It is very ugly that a nice answer have a 0 score.

Comment: now i can vote too. i just didn't have enough rep to upvote until now